# What happens if you put a semi colon after while statment in C++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, syntax

When i put a semi colon after while in this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i = 1, n =1 ;
    while (i > 10);{
        cout << n << ") " << "Hello world! \n";
            i++;
            n++;
    } 
cout << "Hi world !";
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it print Hello world! once and then Hi world! is it just useless and why ?

Comment: `while (i > 10);` is equivalent to `while (i > 10) {}`.

Comment: Since `i` is `1`, the `while (1 > 10)` is `while (false)`.  So that part is what I'd consider useless, but sometimes code is "useless" while it is in the midst of being crafted.  When I have a null statement for a loop (not very common), in order to make it more visible one could do `while (i > 10) continue;` (helps indicate that it was not a typo or oversight, but rather it was intentional).

Comment: "Is it useless" is hilarious because that implies it's something people actually do. It's not. It's bad code. You separated your while statement from the loop body, and the *only* reason you didn't get stuck in an invisible infinite loop is because your loop's Boolean expression is using the wrong comparator.

Comment: The grammar of a `while` loop is `while (condition) statement`. Usually a compound statement is used--that's the `{ ... }` block. However, `;` by itself is a statement: It is a [null statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Expression_statements) and it does nothing.

Comment: Compilers will [warn](https://godbolt.org/z/7q1r9PssK) about this code not doing what you want. Get into the habit of enabling as many warnings as you can.

Comment: ok ,the part that ` while (1 >10) ` was actually intended because i wanted to see if it wont execute the code at all or not

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon after the while statement means a null statement. That is the sub-statement of the while statement is the null statement.

So in fact you have

```
while (i > 10) /* null statement*/;

/* compound statement */
{
    cout << n << ") " << "Hello world! \n";
        i++;
        n++;
}
```

As initially i is not greater than 10 then the while loop will not be executed and the control will be passed to the compound statement. where the string "Hello world!" is outputted.

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps you could check to see if the question is a duplicate before answering? For questions like this one, it's rather unlikely that it's never been asked before, and there's no value to answer them again. If you do have a novel answer, you should definitely post it on the target.